# Sending an Intent to browser to open specific URL with adb shell

Tags: android, shell, android-intent

the intent to launch QQbrowser is :

```
#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;
launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.tencent.mtt/.SplashActivity;end
```

i use the shell to send this intent to launch QQbrowse,and it successed.

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 
-n com.tencent.mtt/.SplashActivity
```

my QQbrowser created a shorcut on my home（desktop）,it's intent are as follows:

```
http://www.baidu.com#Intent;action=com.tencent.QQBrowser.action.SHORTCUT;
package=com.tencent.mtt;b.fromWhere=23;end
```

i try to use

```
am start -a com.encent.QQBrowser.action.SHORTCUT -d http://www.baidu.com          
-n com.tencent.mtt --ei b.fromWhere 23
```

to send intent,but it occurred an error:
`Error: Bad component name: com.tencent.mtt`
I don't konw how to write this command。

how can i send this intent with adb shell？

Comment: Do you get an error? How do you recieve the intent?

Comment: I have edit my question,please help me.And i am sorry that i don't konw how to recieve the intent, i just think sent an intent then it woks~~~